# Xamarin/monotouch UILabel multiline

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am trying to add a multiline UILabel form code.
After reading some questions it seems the answer is to add this:

```
textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

The problem is I don't see it available in mono touch.

Does anyone know how to do it in mono touch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you're looking for is probably the [LineBreakMode property](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=P%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UILabel.LineBreakMode) of UILabel, which takes a [UILineBreakMode](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UILineBreakMode) enum value. So something like this:

```
textLabel.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
textLabel.Lines = 0;
```

Comment: Do you have to do something else to get the text to actually display below the first line, ie. for the wrapped text to show?